# creating xslt 1.0 to group element

Tags: xslt

Could you please help me with grouping in xslt .
Input.xml :

```
     <EDI>
     <Header/>
     <Data>
     <ISA> <Identifier>123</Identifier>
     </ISA>
    <Function>
    <Transaction>
    <BPR><Account> 123<Account></BPR>
    <CUR><Code>USD</Code></CUR>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
    <BPR><Account> 123<Account></BPR>
    <CUR><Code>EUR</Code></CUR>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
    <BPR><Account> 123<Account></BPR>
    <CUR><Code>USD</Code></CUR>
    </Transaction>
    </Function>
    </Data>
    </EDI>
```

I want to group the input xml based on CUR/Code . I have created key and generateid also but the in my output xml it reflecting ISA field value also before Output.

Output xml :

```
<Output>
<Filename>USAFile</Filename> (If the current-group has Code USD)
<EDI>
<Data><ISA><Identifier>12</Identifier></ISA>
<Function>
<Transaction>
<BPR><Account> 123<Account></BPR>
<CUR><Code>USD</Code></CUR>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
<BPR><Account> 123<Account></BPR>
<CUR><Code>USD</Code></CUR>
</Transaction>
</Function>
</Data>
</EDI>
</Output>

<Output>
<Filename>EURFile</Filename> (If the current-group has Code EUR)
<EDI>
<Data><ISA><Identifier>23</Identifier></ISA>
<Function>
<Transaction>
<BPR><Account> 123<Account></BPR>
<CUR><Code>EUR/Code></CUR>
</Transaction>
</Data>
</EDI>
</Output>
```

XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tib="http://www.tibco.com/bw/xslt/custom-functions" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:key name="groups" match="/EDI/Data/Function/Transaction" use="CUR/Code" />
      <xsl:template match="Function">
      <Function>
        <xsl:for-each select="Transaction[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', CUR/Code)[1])]"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('groups',CUR/Code)">
            <Transaction>
              <BR><Account><xsl:value-of select="BPR/Account"/></Account>
              <CUR><Code><xsl:value-of select="CUR/Code"/></Code>
            </Transaction>
          </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Function>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you are having trouble with, as if you are using `xsl:key` and `generate-id` then you are probably not far off the solution. Thanks!

Comment: <xsl:key name="groups" match="/EDI/Data/Function/Transaction" use="CUR/Code" />


  <xsl:template match="Function">
  <Function>
    <xsl:for-each select="Transaction[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', CUR/Code)[1])]"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('groups',CUR/Code)">
        <Transaction>
          <BR><Account><xsl:value-of select="BPR/Account"/></Account>
          <CUR><Code><xsl:value-of select="CUR/Code"/></Code>
        </Transaction>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
    </Function>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: The above I had tested to check if the grouping is correct or not . But the ISA value is coming before the structure . Could you please help with the xslt and let me know where to apply template match when we require the above desired output . Thank you .

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that XSLT. It's hard to read code in comments, you see. Thanks!

Comment: I have added the xslt but it is not reflecting in the question . Could you please take the xslt from Comment and paste in notepad++ . Hope that will help . Or you could help with the xslt for the desired output . Sorry for the xslt not reflecting in question.

Comment: Please edit your question again and clarify what is the output you want to get.

Comment: I have already posted the input and output xml . Grouping should be done on CUR/Code field . If it is 'USD' then separate Output is generated and if it 'EUR' then separate Output is generated. Please help.

Comment: Your expected output isn't well formed. Your stylesheet is missing some instructions otherwise it couldn't output what you expected.

Comment: The expected output should have 2 Output message based on the CUR/Code .Can anyone explain me where can I put apply-template and template match to get the desired output .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly making your input XML well formed as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EDI>
<Header />
<Data>
    <ISA>
        <Identifier>123</Identifier>
    </ISA>
    <Function>
        <Transaction>
            <BPR>
                <Account>
                    123
                </Account>
            </BPR>
            <CUR>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </CUR>
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
            <BPR>
                <Account>
                    123
                </Account>
            </BPR>
            <CUR>
                <Code>EUR</Code>
            </CUR>
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
            <BPR>
                <Account>
                    123
                </Account>
            </BPR>
            <CUR>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </CUR>
        </Transaction>
    </Function>
</Data>
</EDI>
```

Using a bit different approach than what you tried (in case if it is okay with your case):

**Note:** In your output XML, you have shown two different values for `<Identifier>` in `<ISA>`. I guessed it as typo. Correct me if I am missing something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="groups" match="/EDI/Data/Function/Transaction" use="CUR/Code" />

<xsl:template match="Function">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="group" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Transaction[count(. | key('groups',CUR/Code)[1]) = 1]" mode="group">
    <Output>
        <Filename>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="CUR/Code = 'USD'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'USAFile'" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="CUR/Code = 'EUR'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'EURFile'" />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Filename>
        <EDI>
            <Data>
                <ISA>
                    <Identifier>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]" />
                    </Identifier>
                </ISA>
                <Function>
                    <Transaction>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="key('groups',CUR/Code)" />
                    </Transaction>
                </Function>
            </Data>
        </EDI>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ISA" />

<!-- remove nodes other than through the key -->
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="group" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq63